# H NMR signals in 1,4-dichlorobutane spectrum

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy

I have come across H NMR spectrum of 1,4-dichlorobutane and I have noticed that signals there are different to what I would intuitively expect. Instead two triplets there are two multiplets of more complicated structure. I wonder why that is. Looks to me like some higher order spectrum, but I'm not sure. I don't think that is the matter of spectrometer frequency. I wonder if that is some instance of magnetic inequivalence (at the first glance in 1,4-dichlorobutane there are two sets of methylene groups with enantiotopic hydrogen atoms). Can someone clear that out for me?

[image]

Comment: The pairs (C1/C4 and C2/C3) of CH2's are chemically equivalent but magnetically non-equivalent. Here is a perfect answer: http://u-of-o-nmr-facility.blogspot.com/2009/08/500-mhz-1-h-nmr-spectrum-of-butane.html

Comment: If it were _only_ to the spectrometer's field strength (and eventually, the resonance frequencies of the nuclei), then AIST's entry about the same compound ([here](https://sdbs.db.aist.go.jp/sdbs/cgi-bin/landingpage?sdbsno=1277), peak data available, too) possibly could be "better" (i.e. more like the anticipated pattern) because it was recorded at about 400 MHz.  Yet equally, the resolution (data points per ppm), design of the probe head (e.g., what receiver coil is closer to the sample) may interfere _on top_ to `user55119`'s comment.

Comment: Yes, your intuition is correct. The enantiotopic protons are the key.

Comment: Is this spectrum further complicated by the $^2J$ coupling to the chlorine atoms, or is their relaxation time too short to make any difference? Their $\gamma_0$ is about a tenth of that of hydrogen, so I'd guess the coupling constant would be ~1 Hz?

Comment: @Karl _Suggestion:_ Why not posting this as a new question, e.g. H-Cl coupling in NMR spectroscopy?  Both chlorine isotopes seem to be as similar receptive as e.g., phosphorous ([ref Cl](http://chem.ch.huji.ac.il/nmr/techniques/1d/row3/cl.html), [ref P](http://chem.ch.huji.ac.il/nmr/techniques/1d/row3/p.html)), thus it may yield an interesting broader insight ChemSE strives for, too.

Comment: @Buttonwood Gammazero is similar, but phosphorus is spin 1/2, both chlorine isotopes are 3/2. Dont want to get downvoted because of a lack of research effort, and also don't feel like studying tonight. ;-)